# Scenekit rendering blurry only along X axis

Tags: ios, objective-c, scenekit

I have a .dae model exported from blender of some terrain with a texture using SCNWrapModeRepeat along both S and T. when the camera is facing directly along the Z axis the texture shows perfectly clear, when the camera rotates it becomes increasingly blurry.

I have tried changing Min/Mag/Mip filters to Nearest or None and both options create a pixelated view with the camera facing along the X axis.

Note: When the camera position changes the situation is identical across the entire model.

Edit: Just noticed that the faces in the UV are rectangular, could the issue be the texture not being the same scale?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot that shows the blurriness?

Comment: I'm having some issues uploading screenshots, however I did notice although along the z axis is clearer it does get blurry as well. The mip filter setting is changing it from blurry to pixelated when set to nearest or none.